# ¿Por qué se da el error: "Cannot invoke equalsIgnoreCase(String) on the primitive type boolean"?

Tags: java

Tengo un error en la línea donde comparo el string:

```
if(climatizador.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
```

El mensaje es el siguiente:

> Cannot invoke equalsIgnoreCase(String) on the primitive type boolean

¿Por qué?

Este es mi código completo:

```
package poo;

public class Coche {

    private int ruedas;

    private int largo;

    private int ancho;

    private int motor;

    private int peso_plataforma;

    private String color;

    private int peso_total;

    private boolean asientos_cuero, climatizador;

    public Coche() {

        ruedas = 4;

        largo = 2000;

        ancho = 300;

        motor = 1600;

        peso_plataforma = 500;

    }

    public String dime_largo() { // GETTER

        return "El largo del coche es " + largo;

    }

    public void establece_color(String color_coche) { // SETTER

        color = color_coche;

    }

    public String dime_datos_generales() {

        return "La plataforma del vehículo tiene " + ruedas + " ruedas " + 
        ". Mide " + largo/1000 + " metros con un ancho de " + ancho + 
        " cm y un peso de plataforma de " + peso_plataforma + " kg";

    }

    public String dime_color() {

        return "El color del coche es " + color;

    }

    public void configura_asientos(String asientos_cuero) { // SETTER

        if(asientos_cuero.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {

            this.asientos_cuero = true;

        }else {

            this.asientos_cuero = false;

        }

    }

    public String dime_asientos() { // GETTER

        if(asientos_cuero == true) {

            return "El coche tiene asientos de cuero";

        }else {

            return "El coche tiene asientos de serie";

        }

    }

    public void configura_climatizador() { // SETTER

        if(climatizador.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {

            this.climatizador = true;

        }else {

            this.climatizador = false;

        }

    }

    public String dime_climatizador() { //GETTER

        if(climatizador == true) {

            return "El coche incorpora climatizador";

        } else {

            return "El coche lleva aire acondicionado";

        }

    }

    public String dime_peso_coche() { // SETTER + GETTER

        int peso_carroceria = 500;

        peso_total = peso_plataforma + peso_carroceria;

        if(asientos_cuero == true) {

            peso_total = peso_total + 50;

        }

        if(climatizador == true) {

            peso_total = peso_total + 20;

        }

        return "El peso del coche es " + peso_total;

    }

    public int precio_coche() {

        int precio_final = 10000;

        if(asiento_cuero == true) {

            precio_final += 2000;

        }

        if(climatizador == true) {

            precio_final += 1500;

        }

        return precio_final;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

El error más claro no puede ser. Estás llamando a un método sobre una variable cuyo tipo de dato es primitivo. Por demás, el método `equalsIgnoreCase()` pertenece a la clase `String`, asi que aunque la variable `climatizador` fuera de tipo `Boolean`, seguirías teniendo error.

Para solucionar esto solo debes cambiar el `if` que tienes con error por este:

```
if (climatizador) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto podría ayudar a reducir un poco tu código:

```
//Declarar las variables del mismo tipo juntas, ya que no son tantas

private int ruedas, largo, ancho, motor, peso_plataforma, peso_total;
private String color;
private boolean asientos_cuero, climatizador;
```

Para tu problema, obviamente se trata de que estás comprobando un valor de tipo `String` cuando el tipo de la variable es `boolean`. Prueba lo siguiente:

```
public void configura_climatizador(String userClimatizador) { // SETTER

    if(userClimatizador == "si")
//Suponiendo que fuera creas la variable tipo String según lo ingresado por el usuario.
        this.climatizador = true;
}

//Además, he eliminado el else. Al tratarse de booleans, 
//basta con declararlo false al incio de tu código.
```

No he utilizado el `equalsIgnoreCase` porque no hay tantas posibilidades, tan solo dos. Me parece más reducido utilizar el `==`.

Comment: Tenía entendido que en Java para comparar un String se usaba el método equalsIgnoreCase.